# Help with finishing translation

Tags: translation, german-to-english

I recently wanted to see if the owner of a domain name was possibly interested in selling it to me.  I don't speak German, so I had to use Google Translate to compose the email.  She responded in German, and Google Translate provided a good-enough translation to know that she's not interested.  However the translation they provided looks weird.  Can someone clarify what her first sentence means?

German:

> die Domain gebe ich mit Sicherheit nicht her ... von daher keinerlei
>   Interesse.

Here's what Google Translate provides:

> I give the domain certainly not her ... therefore of no interest.

Can someone give a better translation of at least the first half?

And I am confused about the use of "her" in "hergeben" and "von daher" in the reply.

Comment: @splattne: I "broadened" the question by asking about the use of hergeben and daher in the reply, and was wondering if the question could be reopened as being no longer "too localized." A reply to the last sentence would certainly help me, and probably quite a few "future visitors."

Comment: @TomAu I've reopened the question.

Comment: I find the edit questionable. If the OP would have known *hergeben* then they might not have asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"I will definitely not give away the domain, therefore I am not interested."

**EDIT**: "her geben" ("ich gebe die domain her") does not necessarily imply the involvement of money transfer or any other form of payment, but in this context it does.

Answer (score 0):

"Die Domain gebe ich mit Sicherheit nicht her" can be recast as,

Ich wird mit Sicherheit nich die Domain **her**geben." I will definitely not give the domain away. [literally "from here"]

"Von da**her** keinerlei Interesse." Based on this [here], there is no interest.

The confusion appears to arise from the fact that "her" is used twice, both in a German context. It would not be used in English, which is why I put the (literal) translations of "here" in brackets.